# Check Radio based on label text

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<input type="radio" value="213490" id="lt_1133041_213490" name="lt_1133041[]">
<label for="lt_1133041_213490">LH License</label>
<input type="radio" value="213491" id="lt_1133041_213491" name="lt_1133041[]">
<label for="lt_1133041_213491">PC License</label>
```

What I need to do is to be able to check the radio based on the label text, so if I pass "LH License" it will check id lt_1133041_213490, if I pass "PC License", it will check id lt_1133041_213491.

Not sure exactly how to do that.

Comment: Found the answer and will post when able. No need to post answers or comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
id = $("label:contains("+label_text+")").attr('for');
$('#' + id).prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/xjMLH/).

```
function checkRadio(text){
    $('#'+$('label:contains('+text+')').attr('for')).attr('checked', 'checked');  
}

checkRadio('LH License');
```

This creates a function that when passed a string will check the appropriate radio button.

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkRadio( text){
    $('input:radio').filter(function(){
      return $(this).next('label').text()==text;
    }).prop('checked', true);\

}
```

To use function:

```
checkRadio( 'LH License');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly.

```
var _radio = $("label:contains('LH License')").attr("for");
i = $("#" + _radio).attr('id');
```

Comment: Was just getting id and then checking but @Barmar's solution is better.

Comment: That second statement doesn't do anything useful, it just sets `i` to the same thing as `_radio`.